# symfony yaml: keep new lines (literal)

Tags: symfony, yaml, multiline

I am trying to keep newlines in a yaml file.
In a messages.en.yml file, I have.

```
test:|
  Here is line 1
  Here is line 2
```

And in form.html.twig:

{{'test'|trans}}

Both lines are rendered on the same line.
      Here is line 1 Here is line 2

In [this link](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/yaml/yaml_format.html), the literal style for Yaml is explained.
and [in this other one](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html), it says "Notable lacking features are: document directives, multi-line quoted messages ..."

So is it possible in Symfony Yaml to use multilines? and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `|nl2br` [filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html)

```
{{ 'test'|trans|nl2br }}
```

Or, if you are sure your translation can't get altered by any user, you could use some few html in your translation.

```
test:|
  Here is line 1<br/>
  Here is line 2<br/>
  <br/><br/>
  Here is line 5
```

Then

```
{{ 'test'|trans|raw }}
```